# How can I select and insert BLOB between different databases using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, blob

I have some SQL Server tables that contain Image data types.
I want to make it somehow usable in PostgreSQL. I'm a python programmer, so I have a lot of learn about this topic. Help?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you grabbed the appropriate drivers? Installing pymssql (http://code.google.com/p/pymssql/) and psycopg2 (http://www.initd.org/psycopg/) are going to be your first step.

Comment: The first thing is to decide whether you want to store the images in a `bytea` column, use the "large objects" feature (to treat as `BLOB` data), or use external files with a reference in the database. I've generally gone with `bytea` columns, but above 10MB or 20MB per value that tends to get clumsy.

Comment: Mike Steder: I have pymssql and psycopg2. I have experience with using postgres  and python in general. the images are very small. no more than 100KB. I'll look at bytea columns. thansk

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand first is that the interfaces at the db level are likely to be different.  Your best option is to write an abstraction layer for the blobs (and maybe publish it open source for the dbs you want to support).

On the PostgreSQL side you need to figure out whether you want to bo with bytea or lob.  These are very different and have different features and limitations.  If you are enterprising you might build in at least support in the spec for selecting them.  In general bytea is better for smaller files while lob has more management overhead but it can both support larger files and supports chunking, seeking etc.